# In-app Purchase in ANDGINE

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, andengine

Have a small game in ANDENGINE in which i have three slides

```
Title
Activity_One
Activity_Two
```

Now i want to make Activity one and Activity two Purchase able. In short words implement in app in ANDENGINE Project So the famous in app-3 Google will be used or there are other methods to enable in-app purchase in ANDENGINE. searched on net but did not find any relevant sol or info. any help would be appricited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's in-app works (I've used it). So do anyone else's, like amazon, etc. The in app api's do not tie to your game implementation. Use what you think will get you the best return from your target audience.

Just be prepared, in-app is a bit of work.